# Fear of Overwriting Referenced Data in Struct

Tags: c, pointers, stm32, garbage

I have a question regarding a data buffer pointer and I don't know how to search Google for this problem because I don't know what it might be called. So...

I have a function that takes a structure PCA9745 and configures some of it's parameters with the function inputs as seen below. My concern is about the array pointers... When the function *_PCA9745_Configure()* completes, do the arrays (to the buffers) get released after the function returns, thus making the array pointer useless as it may get written over?

I'd like a way to create array references that don't become obsolete once the function returns without declaring arrays in **main.c** to hide some ugliness and make it more user friendly.

**PCA9745_io.c**

```
void _PCA9745_Configure(PCA9745 *p, float r_ext, uint16_t num_dev){
    p->r_ext = r_ext;
    p->num_dev = num_dev;
    uint8_t instr_buffer[num_dev];
    uint8_t data_buffer[num_dev];
    uint8_t rx_buffer[num_dev];
    p->instr_buffer = &instr_buffer;
    p->data_buffer = &data_buffer;
    p->rx_buffer = &rx_buffer;
}
```

**The PCA9745 Structure**

```
typedef struct {
    SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi;
    GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_port_nCS;
    uint16_t gpio_pin_nCS;
    GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_port_nOE;
    uint16_t gpio_pin_nOE;

    //Must include for PCA9745.c to compile
    float r_ext;            //External Resistor value
    uint16_t num_dev;       //number of devices
    uint8_t *instr_buffer[];
    uint8_t *data_buffer[];
    uint8_t *rx_buffer[];
} PCA9745;
```

**main.c**

```
PCA9745 p = Init_PCA9745(&hspi1, nCS_GPIO_Port, nCS_Pin, nOE_GPIO_Port, nOE_Pin);
_PCA9745_Configure(&p, 3600.0f, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, they are released because they are local. Is dynamic allocation (`malloc()`, etc.) supported in your platform?

Comment: The `_PCA9745_Configure()` function is incorrect, as its pointer members contain the address of local variables that will end life when you return from the function. You have mismatching indirection too, because (I think, those are only code fragments) the member `uint8_t *instr_buffer[];` should be `uint8_t *instr_buffer;` If you don't want references that become obsolete, use `malloc`, and `free` them before you `free` the `struct`.

Comment: Your `PCA9745` is not valid C because it has three flexible array members at the end. Only the last member is allowed to be a flexible array member (and only if it is not the only member of the struct).

Comment: @IanAbbott IMO they should not be arrays of pointers but `uint8_t *instr_buffer` etc as commented. The indirection level does not match.

Comment: @WeatherVane TBH, it's hard to find anything at all that isn't wrong in the code!

Comment: @MikeCAT no malloc on stm32.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this personally, but if you want to be fancy you could return a struct from init.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define PCA9745_BUF_SIZE 512

typedef struct {
    //SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi; // I dont have these types :)
    //GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_port_nCS;
    //GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_port_nOE;
    uint16_t gpio_pin_nOE;
    uint16_t gpio_pin_nCS; 
    uint16_t num_dev;       //number of devices
    float r_ext;            //External Resistor value 
    uint8_t *instr_buffer;
    uint8_t *data_buffer;
    uint8_t *rx_buffer;
} PCA9745_t;

static uint8_t instr_buf[PCA9745_BUF_SIZE];
static uint8_t data_buf[PCA9745_BUF_SIZE];
static uint8_t rx_buf[PCA9745_BUF_SIZE];

void _PCA9745_init(PCA9745_t *p);

int main(void)
{

    PCA9745_t PCA9745 = 
    {
        //.hspi = &spi1,
        //.gpio_port_nCS = my_favorite_gpio,
        //...,
        .instr_buffer = instr_buf,
        .data_buffer = data_buf,
        .rx_buffer = rx_buf
    };
    
    _PCA9745_init(&PCA9745);
    
    // Just for test :)
    for(int i = 0; i < PCA9745_BUF_SIZE; i++){
    printf("%d",*(PCA9745.rx_buffer+i));
    }
    
  return 0;
}


void _PCA9745_init(PCA9745_t *p){
    memset(p->instr_buffer,0,PCA9745_BUF_SIZE);
    memset(p->data_buffer,0,PCA9745_BUF_SIZE);
    memset(p->rx_buffer,9,PCA9745_BUF_SIZE); // fill it with something known
    //.....
    p->r_ext = 1;
    p->num_dev = 1;
}
```